# HTML in a JSON String in Java

Tags: java, html, json, string, gson

I want to save a **Java** class named `MyClass` into a text file and I want to use *JSON* to encode the class for file writing purposes instead of implementing the `Serializable` interface. Moreover, to save the class I want to use the Google's [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson) library and in particular the [`JsonWriter`](http://google-son.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html) class. The `MyClass` class is, for instance, defined as follows:

```
public class MyClass{
 String html;    
 public MyClass(){}
}
```

As shown in the example above, `MyClass` has a `String` field named `html`, that obviously must contain *HTML code*.

Can I save the class into a text file by using JSON via the `JsonWriter` or I should encode or do something similar with the `html` field (e.g. a call to an `URLEncode`-like function) before to give it to `JsonWriter`?

Comment: What happened when you tried to serialize it ?

Comment: I don't wan't to serialize the class because after I save it I need to use it in a non-Java application.

Comment: Looks like you can, but is that really a good design?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I need to import the class data into another program then. Is there any better way to save the file without using Java serialization?

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish it? Asking *can I do this without even trying myself?* is not an option here.

Comment: The JSON encoder should escape any characters it's sensitive to (which I think is just quotes).  Your main problem would be that some encoders (dunno about Gson) gratuitously escape other characters, and you'd have to undo those escapes on the other end.

Comment: @Hot Licks I did some test in reading/writing, from a text file. Everything seems to work fine! But, honestly, I cannot test all the different HTML tags and text combinations so I cannot guarantee that I will not get errors!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thank you for the style lesson! My question is very simple since I stated that I use `JsonWriter`! What do you think I tried? I used `writer.name("html").value(myobject.html);`, i.e. the only thing I think that one can do with `JsonWriter`. My question is about experience (Yes you can why... or no you can't, but you can...).

Comment: Since escaping new lines / quotes etc can make this a little tricky, why not just use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to convert the object to XML and wrap the [HTML in a CDATA section](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) ? Json has no equivalent for a CDATA section.

Comment: @DeepakBala This seems a very good idea/alternative. A lot of bytes will be used wrt JSON, but works! Please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since escaping new lines / quotes etc can make this a little tricky, why not just use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) to convert the object to XML and wrap the HTML in a CDATA section ? Json has no equivalent for a [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) section.